# Script won't load

Tags: 2013, error, https, script

I'm having some issues with a SP 2013 site trying to access through an F5 
firewall. Everything works fine internally, but outside the network, Grouped Views won't even load and the Ribbon is disabled. Is this an infrastructure thing or have any of you Devs / Admins seen this happen before?

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the site added to trusted sites? I've seen a site not load JavaScript because of IE security zones. Does this work in Chrome / Firefox or is problem only there with IE?

Comment: I tried adding to Trusted sites but it didn't help. It's happening in all browsers.

Comment: Do you have custom js on your page? https://controlzet.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/sp-js-not-load-on-sharepoint-pages/

Comment: nothing custom exists. OOB list views are broken, ribbon doesn't work

Comment: Can you check what all js files have been loaded using f12?